# Fastest way to count PDF images using PDFBox 2.x

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

We occasionally encounter some extremely large PDFs filled with full page, high resolution images (the result of document scanning). For example, I have a 1.7GB PDF with 3500+ images. Loading the document takes about 50s but counting the images takes about 15 minutes.

I'm sure this is because the image bytes are read as a part of the API calls. Is there way to extract the image count without actually reading the image bytes?

PDFBox version: 2.0.2

Example Code:

```
@Test
public void imageCountIsCorrect() throws Exception {
    PDDocument pdf = readPdf();
    try {
        assertEquals(3558, countImages(pdf));
        // assertEquals(3558, countImagesWithExtractor(pdf));
    } finally {
        if (pdf != null) {
            pdf.close();
        }
    }
}

protected PDDocument readPdf() throws IOException {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("large.pdf");
    PDDocument pdf;
    try {
        pdf = PDDocument.load(stream, MemoryUsageSetting.setupMixed(1024 * 1024 * 250));
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }

    stopWatch.stop();
    log.info("PDF loaded: time={}s", stopWatch.getTime() / 1000);
    return pdf;
}


protected int countImages(PDDocument pdf) throws IOException {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    int imageCount = 0;
    for (PDPage pdPage : pdf.getPages()) {
        PDResources pdResources = pdPage.getResources();
        for (COSName cosName : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
            PDXObject xobject = pdResources.getXObject(cosName);
            if (xobject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                imageCount++;
                if (imageCount % 100 == 0) {
                    log.info("Found image: #" + imageCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stopWatch.stop();
    log.info("Images counted: time={}s,imageCount={}", stopWatch.getTime() / 1000, imageCount);
    return imageCount;
}
```

If I change the countImages method to rely on the COSName, the count completes in less than 1s but I'm a little uncertain about relying on the prefix of the name. This appears to be a byproduct of the pdf encoder and not PDFBox (I couldn't find any reference to it in their code):

```
if (cosName.getName().startsWith("QuickPDFIm")) {
    imageCount++;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, your code only counts the immediate bitmap image *resources* per page. It neither consists inlined images nor images contained in xobject or patterns. On the other hand an image resource needs not be used on a page. Thus, sometimes you'll also count too many images. For a generic solution you'll need to consider the content stream.

Comment: Ahh, that would explain some of the inconsistencies I found between image counts when I was using a custom implementation of PDFGraphicsStreamEngine to count images.  I'll dig into that code to find out what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: What I have in mind is to modify the ExtractImages example and remove all that creates image objects, and call `addOperator(new DrawObject());` with a `DrawObject extends GraphicsOperatorProcessor` processor that would not create the xobjects if it is an image but would follow forms. See the source code of org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.DrawObject.

Comment: I see...  my initial fail was to extend PDFGraphicsStreamEngine with NOOP methods except drawImage which incremented a count. Looks like I should have extended PDFStreamEngine with the addOperator as you have described instead. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Comment: Added an answer based on your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the previous approach had some additional flaws (could miss inline images, etc.). Thanks mkl and Tilman Hausherr for the feedback!

[TIL - PDF object streams contain useful operator codes!](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html)

My new approach extends PDFStreamEngine and increments an imageCount for every 'Do' (draw object) operator found in the PDF content stream. The image count only takes a few hundred milliseconds with this method:

```
public class PdfImageCounter extends PDFStreamEngine {
    protected int documentImageCount = 0;

    public int getDocumentImageCount() {
        return documentImageCount;
    }

    public PdfImageCounter() {
        addOperator(new OperatorProcessor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Operator operator, List<COSBase> arguments) throws IOException {
                if (arguments.size() < 1) {
                    throw new MissingOperandException(operator, arguments);
                }
                if (isImage(arguments.get(0))) {
                    documentImageCount++;
                }
            }

            protected Boolean isImage(COSBase base) {
                return (base instanceof COSName) &&
                        context.getResources().isImageXObject((COSName)base);
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "Do";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Invoke it for each page:

```
protected int countImagesWithProcessor(PDDocument pdf) throws IOException {
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    PdfImageCounter counter = new PdfImageCounter();
    for (PDPage pdPage : pdf.getPages()) {
        counter.processPage(pdPage);
    }

    stopWatch.stop();
    int imageCount = counter.getDocumentImageCount();
    log.info("Images counted: time={}s,imageCount={}", stopWatch.getTime() / 1000, imageCount);
    return imageCount;
}
```

Comment: But you're not crawling operands that are not images, e.g. PDFormXObject. Have a look at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.DrawObject. This one has an interesting strategy to avoid creating images.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the answer updated to skip objects which are not really images.

Comment: What I meant is more than that. If you hit a form or a transparency group, you need to process that too, like org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.DrawObject does. These can also contain images. Next thing to do is to make sure that the images are unique, use a Set<COSBase>.